# Obtain nodes that don't have specific ancestor xml xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, ancestor

I would like to have xpath, that obtains nodes, that don't have ancestor, which is first descendant of specific node.

Let's assume we have xml document like this:

```
<a>
  <b>This node</b>
  <c>
    <a>
      <b>not this</b>
      <g>
        <b>not this</b>
      </g>
    </a>
    <a>
      <b>This node</b>
      <c/>
    </a>
  </c>
</a>


<a>
  <c>
    <a>
      <b>not this</b>
    </a>
    <a>
      <b>This node</b> 
    </a>
    <a>
      <b>This node</b> 
    </a>
    <a>
      <b>This node</b> 
    </a>
  </c>
</a>


<d>
  <b>This node</b>
</d>
```

I would like to select all b nodes in document that don't have as their ancestor node //a/c/a[1].

Comment: This *is not* a well-formed XML document. It is severely malformed!!!

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, now it should be ok.

Comment: It still isn't well-formed -- a well-formed XML document has exactly one top element. The one you in the question has three top-level elements.

Comment: I have given you the answer that you needed. Any questions, or is everything understood?

Comment: Everything is clear, I did have hard time to get the idea how it works :). Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to select all b nodes in
>   document that don't have as their
>   ancestor node `//a/c/a[1]`

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
//b[not(ancestor::a
             [parent::c[parent::a]
            and
              not(preceding-sibling::a)
             ]
       )
   ]
```

This selects all `b` elements in the document that don't have ancestor `a` that has a parent `c` that has parent `a` *and* the `a` ancestor that has parent `c` is not the first `a` child of its parent.

**Given the following XML document** (based on the provided, but made well-formed and also put identifying text in the nodes that should be selected):

```
<t>
    <a>
        <b>This node 1</b>
        <c>
            <a>
                <b>not this</b>
                <g>
                    <b>not this</b>
                </g>
            </a>
            <a>
                <b>This node 2</b>
                <c/>
            </a>
        </c>
    </a>
    <a>
        <c>
            <a>
                <b>not this</b>
            </a>
            <a>
                <b>This node 3</b>
            </a>
            <a>
                <b>This node 4</b>
            </a>
            <a>
                <b>This node 5</b>
            </a>
        </c>
    </a>
    <d>
        <b>This node 6</b>
    </d>
</t>
```

**exactly the wanted 6 `b` elements are selected.**

**Verification using XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:copy-of select=
 "//b[not(ancestor::a
             [parent::c[parent::a]
            and
              not(preceding-sibling::a)
             ]
         )
     ]

 "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, exactly the wanted `b` elements are selected and copied to the output. The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<b>This node 1</b>
<b>This node 2</b>
<b>This node 3</b>
<b>This node 4</b>
<b>This node 5</b>
<b>This node 6</b>
```